# Unwanted UIView frame reset after inserting text in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, frame, uikeyboard

I'm stuck with some funny problem and ran out of ideas how to solve it. 
In one of my controllers I use a simple scheme of adjusting a view frame according to the keyboard appearance.

In `UITextFieldDelegate` method I initialise the controller's property `firstResponder`:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    self.firstResponder = textField
}
```

Then I use UIKeyboard notifications selectors to change the frame of `contentView`:

```
override func keyboardWillShow(_ notifications: Notification) {
    super.keyboardWillShow(notifications)

    let info = notifications.userInfo
    let keyboardFrame:CGRect = (info![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let duration:Double = (info![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).doubleValue

    var bottomY:CGFloat!

    if self.firstResponder == self.emailTextField{
        bottomY = self.emailBottomLine.frame.origin.y + 80 + self.headerView.frame.height
    }
    else {
        return 
    }

    if bottomY >= keyboardFrame.origin.y {

        let offset = bottomY - keyboardFrame.origin.y

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {

            self.contentView.frame.origin.y = -offset
        })

    }else{
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {

            self.contentView.frame.origin.y = self.contentViewOriginY
        })
    }
}

override func keyboardWillHide(_ notifications: Notification) {
    super.keyboardWillHide(notifications)

    let info = notifications.userInfo
    let duration:Double = (info![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).doubleValue

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {

        self.contentView.frame.origin.y = self.contentViewOriginY
    })
}
```

And everything works fine until I start typing inside the `emailTextField`. Each tap on the keyboard causes the `contentView` reset to its original position without animation.

The question is what really causes this behavior? I'm totally confused and have checked whatever thing is possibly affects this. Please, help!!!

Comment: My immediate thought whenever views suddenly reset to their original position after changing their frame is that they might have some layout constraints set on them. Is your `contentView` constrained using layout constraints at all?

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler it sure is. Never thought it may interfere. Gonna check now.

Comment: Ahh okay, yep, that would be why, I'm guessing. You can't really mix constraints and frames, as it will always just snap back to whatever the constraints say the frame of the view should be on the next layout cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure either:

A. Your `contentView` does not have any layout constraints attached to it, or else when you set its frame, its frame will be reset on the next layout pass back to what the constraints say the frame should be.

or:

B. Use a constraint to position your `contentView`'s vertical offset relative to the keyboard instead of adjusting its frame.